FastAPI Request.query_params doesn't return all values
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Query
from typing import List

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test")
async def test(req: Request, q:List[str] = Query(None)):
    

    return req.query_params
    

Test function can accept multiple(list) queries: q. If you run this code and focus on Request, you will see req.query_params returns only the last value of passed queries q.
Is this a bug or it is made on purpose? Is there any solution to get all queries in Request.query_params class? I would appreciate your reply.

This is a Starlette issue. You can access all items by calling req.query_params.multi_items().
You will get
[
  [
    "q",
    "string1"
  ],
  [
    "q",
    "string2"
  ]
]

Or, you can get a list of values for particular parameter: req.query_params.getlist("q")
Results in ["string1", "string2"]
